# Why does @tailrec not permit this function?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I want to do ln(N!) in Scala with `tailrec`

```scala
  @tailrec
  final def recursiveLogN(n: Int): Double = {
    if (n <= 1) {
      return 0
    }
    Math.log(n) + recursiveLogN(n - 1)
  }
```

The compile error:

```
could not optimize @tailrec annotated method recursiveLogN: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
    Math.log(n) + recursiveLogN(n - 1)
```

Comment: The answer is in compiler error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive call should be the last method call, the way your snippet is written it is just part of the last expression.

It can be rewritten to something like:

```scala
  @tailrec
  final def recursiveLogN(n: Int, accum: Double = 0): Double = {
    if (n <= 1) {
      return accum
    }
   recursiveLogN(n - 1, accum+ Math.log(n))
  }
```

And then tail call elimination will be possible

Comment: Use `if else` instead of `return`

Comment: Yeah that would be more idiomatic but did not want to alter the posters snippet more than necessary.